# Cannot figure out why I got coredump in linux assembly

Tags: linux, windows, assembly, x86, x86-64

I'm trying to print a single digit to the terminal in assembly. I'm using the

> AT&T syntax
>
> GNU assembler version 2.26.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1

and I'm using the GNU distribution in Windows 10.

```
.text
.globl main
main:
movq $0x03, %rax
addq $0x30, %rax
movq %rax, %rdi
call puts
movq $0, %rax
ret
```

However I got a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` at execution. What do I do wrong ?

Comment: `puts` expects a pointer to a string. You passed a char. You effectively did `puts('3')` which will fault in C. See [man puts](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/puts.3.html) You probably want `call putchar` instead.

Comment: `push %rax` / `mov %rsp, %rdi` / `call puts` would work, because an 8-byte `push` includes a terminating zero byte after the character, to make a valid C string.  (x86 is little-endian, so the char is in the first byte.)

Comment: @PeterCordes infact the push also helps with satisfying the stack alignment requirement of the ABI on x86_64 Linux.